# .htaccess Rewrite Engine, folder-structure,

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, directory-structure

Havin following folder-structure

- http://somesite.somename.com/

  - ...
  - public

    - ...
    - .htaccess
    - index.php
    - ...
  - ...

And .htaccess structure as following

```
RewriteEngine On


# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The 
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to 
# allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
# in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size 
# fits all solution.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

**Problem** when accessing http://somesite.somename.com/ it shows folder structure to make it work i need to access http://somesite.somename.com/public

**Question** How to make http://somesite.somename.com/public be accessed as http://somesite.somename.com/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have .htaccess at root level (a level above `public`) to forward all traffic to public:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

No change is needed in `/public/.htaccess`

Comment: added .htaccess at root level and wrote your code but also i doesn't seem to work. I then deleted all code and wrote random text to check if it works and server sees .htaccess.